# Python method to round up to the nearest 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a program where if I call

```
get_bin_pos(19.4) ==> output as 20
get_bin_pos(13.4) ==> output as 20
get_bin_pos(31.4) ==> output as 40
```

I wrote something like below, it looks bad, any suggestion in optimizing it ?

Switch statement for this would be more readable, but we don't have a switch in python. So any other way?

```
def get_bin_pos(self, value):
        if value <= 10:
            return 10
        if value <= 20:
            return 20
        if value <= 30:
            return 30
        if value <= 40:
            return 40
        if value <= 50:
            return 50
        if value <= 60:
            return 60
        if value <= 70:
            return 70
```

Comment: `return (int(value / 10) + 1) * 10` perhaps?

Comment: `return int((value + 10) / 10) * 10` (similar to @vnp's suggestion, but more intuitive in my view)

Comment: @vnp `(int(10 / 10) + 1) * 10 == 20`... Maybe not the correct method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you want to `ceil`, then you want to use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.ceil). This is as easy as:

  \$10 \lceil \frac{value}{10} \rceil\$
- You may want to make a generic function to ceil within a bound.
- You can set your somewhat weird limits to the function.

```
import math


def ceil(number, bound=1):
    return bound * math.ceil(number / bound)


def get_bin_pos(value):
    if value > 70:
        return None
    return ceil(max(value, 1), 10)
```